# vector of numbers to specific dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 2 datasets:

1. is a dataframe with date type variables (from 2007-01-01 to 2008-12-31) and values of dollar over time
2. vector `0 216 216 407 508` which i need to convert to date in range as above (0 is 2007-01-01, 216 is 216th day from 2007-01-01 and so on).

Then i need to plot them together where dataframe is main plot, and vector will be vlines on that plot

Do u know how to change that vector to coresponding days and the plot them with ggplot?

```
ggplot(data = data_test, aes(x=day, y=dollar)) +geom_line() +
geom_vline(xintercept = cpt_vec, colour="green", linetype = "longdash")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. You can create the dates adding the min date from `day` in your data with the vector of numbers you have. Here the code with dummy data:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
data_test <- data.frame(day=seq(as.Date('2007-01-01'),as.Date('2008-12-31'),by='1 day'),
                        dollar=rnorm(731,1,10))
#Vector
vdays <- c(0,216,216,407,508)
#New dates
vdates <- min(data_test$day)+vdays
#Plot
ggplot(data = data_test, aes(x=day, y=dollar)) +geom_line() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = vdates, colour="green", linetype = "longdash")
```

Output:

[image]

As reminder, you have two `216` so the line will be in the same position twice.